# Why can't I group input sections from --emit-relocs ld option inside a common output section?

Tags: linker, linker-scripts, relocation, linker-flags

I have to relocate an elf at runtime and so I want to have access to all the relocations emitted by the linker: hence the use of the `--emit-relocs` ld option. The thing is I want to group all the `.rela.*` sections into one `.rela.dyn` section in the linker script and then go through this only section to relocate all the symbols.

But I can't get my linker script to achieve this, I still see a lot of `.rela.*` sections in the final elf and not the output section `.rela.dyn`. The following is what I used in the linker script and actually is simply copied from another architecture linker script that works but that does not use `--emit-relocs`:

```
.rela.dyn : ALIGN(8) {                                                   
    *(.rela .rela*)                                                  
}
```

Does the `--emit-relocs` option 'bypass' the linker script ? Or did I simply miss something ?

Thanks,

Alex